# changing colors when link is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

If I have a menu set up in the header which I use for most of my pages as "include/header.php" how do I setup so when I click on a link, it goes to that page, and that link changes colors (and shows as active)? Would jquery be good? or PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP to add a class to the current button by comparing it's URL, and the current page URL from `$_GET`. Without knowing what your URL structure is like, I can't say much more than that.

For example, using an array with button text and URLs:

```
$links = array('Home' => 'home', 'About' => 'about');

foreach($links as $text => $page)
{
    if($_GET['page'] == $page)
    {
        echo '<a href="/index.php?page=' . $page . ' class="current">' . $text . '</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="/index.php?page=' . $page . '>' . $text . '</a>';
    }
}
```

This code will add a class of `current` to the button who's page matches the value in `$_GET`. This might not exactly fit your needs due to you probably having a different URL structure, among other things, but it gives a basic explanation and example of how to do this.

Comment: this will work if I'm using index.php as my page, but what if the link is different? settings.php, home.php, about.php

Answer (score 2):

Use php, you could write a function before your include like so,

```
function activeLink ($page) {
    if ($page = 'home') echo ' class="active"';
    elseif ($page = 'about') echo ' class="active"';
    elseif ($page = 'posts') echo ' class="active"';
}
```

And in your header file,

```
echo '<a href="#"' . activeLink($page) . '>Home</a>
<a href="#"' . activeLink($page) . '>About</a>
<a href="#"' . activeLink($page) . '>Posts</a>';
```

And on your actual page;

```
$page = 'home';
include('header');
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: apart from a redundant way todo it, your missing the page parameter in `activeLink()`

Comment: What happens if its just pages instead of #, its `<a href='/index.php'>Index</a>`, then `<a href='/about.php'>About</a>`?

Comment: I think the echo is wrong? it'll echo out into the href link?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you write the function before you call it, then in your css just write a style for the class active.

Comment: No it wont, look at where the function is echoed within the qoutes, and where the qoutes are for the href link.

Comment: You could even include the function in your header file, meaning you don't have to include it in every page meaning it is all in one place!

Comment: wait! i just thought that this might not work. If the `$page = home`, then all the links will have `class = active`

Comment: No it won't as they are if, elseif statments if one is true then the others get disregarded!

Comment: but, if it is true. all the links will have active in their class. you're echoing out the same thing in each function

Comment: I think you need to relearn php from basics if you cannot understand my question.

Comment: ... look at it. I think maybe you should think about it.. if the $page = home. then all those links with activeLink($page) will echo class='active'. You're having each link as the same function.

Comment: That is why you change the variable on each page to suit the function, thick as!